# Assert home page title

Tags: java, selenium

How to assert text `"ka"` is present in home page title?

```
String name=element.getText();
Assert.assertTrue(name.contains("ka"));
```

Does my above code work?

Comment: Well... did you run it? *Did* it work?

Comment: i have run it, but its not working

Comment: Then why are you asking if it works? Could you expand on "not working"? Give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first, you need to review if you are getting the title of your page or maybe is an empty string, also some times you need to wail until your page is completely loaded because selenium is fast to get the component's values. Try to share error that is displayed.